# Umbraco - Macro Views not rendering

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco

We are having issues with MacroScripts on our test server. The application works locally and the code/ databases should be identical between the two.

It is failing to render most of the MacroScripts as opposed to just one or two.

> Error loading MacroEngine script (file: Breadcrumb.cshtml)

The stack trace in the error log says:

```
2014-12-01 15:02:06,308 [22] WARN  Umbraco.Web.Routing.DefaultUrlProvider -[Thread     53] Couldn't find any page with nodeId=1658. This is most likely caused by the page not being published.
2014-12-01 15:02:06,323 [22] WARN  umbraco.macro - [Thread 53] Error loading MacroEngine script (file: Breadcrumb.cshtml, Type: ''. Exception: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Any'
at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object )
at ASP._Page_macroScripts_Breadcrumb_cshtml.Execute() in d:\HTTP\Development\Sodexo\MoneyBoostPhase4\MacroScripts\Breadcrumb.cshtml:line 25
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy(IEnumerable`1 executors)
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.ExecuteRazor(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
at umbraco.MacroEngines.RazorMacroEngine.Execute(MacroModel macro, INode currentPage)
at umbraco.macro.loadMacroScript(MacroModel macro)
at umbraco.macro.renderMacro(Hashtable pageElements, Int32 pageId)
```

I'm new to ASP and this issue is baffling me as it's working loaclly, but not on the dev server!

Any help would be most appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy Umbraco code you also need to make sure that the metadata is setup correctly on the target server.  It looks like the target server doesn't have the macro for your BreadCrumb set up - even if it does have the razor code for breadcrumb.cshtml.  Have you also added all your dev metadata to this staging server (doc types, templates, macros, data types etc)?

If you have set up the metadata (doc types, templates, macros, data types etc) then the most likely problem is that you app_data\umbraco.config file is cached & out of date.  So delete it, also delete your examine indexes (in the same folder or subfolders) & give you app pool a restart - umbraco will rebuild its cached files & everything will come together.

Also your error message suggests that some nodes are unpublished - which will also be unhelpful.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by dev meta data? I uploaded the whole Visual Studio project.

I've just tried deleted the umbraco.config file & everything else in the directory and it's still having the same issue.

The developers used to deploy using the same method, so it's not a new configuration, just a new deployment.

Thanks for your quick reply.

Comment: I've just checked the developers machine - the node 1658 is not published locally either, and that environment is working.

Comment: Did you add a macro in development?   By the look of your error you've added a macro called 'Breadcrumb' in your local system, but you've deployed code to the test server & not also added the macro - its not enough to copy the code unless you've got something like Courier working that also sets up the metadata.

Comment: The breadcrumb + other macroscripts have been in the system for months, so I imagine they were set up correctly initally. It just seems that the latest deployment has broken them. Our deployment process is, FTP the whole project solution, and take a dump of the database and reimport that.

Comment: How do you get changes live using that deployment model? Anyway, go into the umbraco back office on your test server, right click on the content node & choose 'republish entire site' - also reboot your app pool in IIS.  Hopefully this will refresh your cache & fix things.

Comment: The 'modified' files are uploaded via FTP, which has worked for the developers  up until now (i'm a PHP developer by trade, but been asked to manage this project and i'm out of my comfort zone as usually I have GIT/ CI set up for deployments!). I've done as you said, with the same result. :(

Comment: OK i've come to the conclusion it's "Model.Ancestors().Any()" that's causing it. Any Macro with that in is dying.

Answer (score 0):

The error is not saying that the breadcrumb macro file is not present - rather is is causing an error

'umbraco.MacroEngines.DynamicNodeList' does not contain a definition for 'Any' on Breadcrumb.cshtml:line 25

Additionally nobody has mentioned the database directly which is where all content and 'meta-data' is stored.

It is very possible that new content /  document types / data types / etc has been added to the local database and has not been deployed to live - deployment in Umbraco, generally includes database changes as well.

Now you know where the error is, you will need to debug.